# Form fields in hidden DIV

Tags: php, javascript

I have a form with some fields that are in a hidden DIV (style="display: none;"). The user can click a button that displays these additional fields if they wish.

Now if the user submits the form in its "compact" state, the form variables in the hidden div are also submitted and displayed in the address bar.

How can I change this behaviour so that only the visible form fields are submitted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use POST instead of GET.

Set the `disabled` attribute to true when the fields are hidden and enable them again when the fields are shown. `disabled` will prevent them from being submitted.

Comment: It's a search form, so it makes life a lot easier to use GET. I will try the disabled attribute, will that work with GET?

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to come up with a JS method that submits the form with only the values you want.  The way its currently working is normal browser behavior. Just because the form fields are visually hidden does not mean they shouldn't be submitted.

If you can, use POST instead of GET and you wont have to worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

Place the DIV outside the FORM element and you should be fine. Do it with script if you are unable to do it from the backend.

Let the toggle callback put the DIV in place if needed, like this I presume:

```
// show
form_elm.appendChild(div_elm);
div_elm.style.display = 'block';

// hide
form_elm.parentNode.appendChild(div_elm);
div_elm.style.display = 'block';
```

You can do this more elegant in your JavaScript library of choice.

Answer (score 0):

That's all css work really.  .hidden_div_1 form {... visibility:hidden; disabled:disabled; readonly:readonly; }

i like to add opacity:0.0; too just because i never know when i want to adjust it later for some other reason.

Comment: alternatively you can switch from one div to another discarding others in your js and server page on click of some button, link, option etc.